# Get date/time having facebook format

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is some java-script library for getting date/time having Facebook format in different languages?

Examples of facebook format are:

```
about an hour ago 

7 minutes ago 

Yesterday at 03:48

Sunday at 18:00

13 mars, à 21:34

11 septembre 2001, à 8:45
```

Comment: any luck finding one that handles ranges nicely too? I’ve seen momentjs and it’s calendar time implementation but it doesn’t work too gracefully with trix js to handle ranges

Answer (score 5):

Try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the king of jQuery's JavaScript Pretty Date
: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

```
prettyDate("2008-01-28T20:24:17Z") // => "2 hours ago"
prettyDate("2008-01-27T22:24:17Z") // => "Yesterday"
prettyDate("2008-01-26T22:24:17Z") // => "2 days ago"
prettyDate("2008-01-14T22:24:17Z") // => "2 weeks ago"
prettyDate("2007-12-15T22:24:17Z") // => undefined
```

- script: http://ejohn.org/files/pretty.js
- demo: http://ejohn.org/files/pretty.html

Comment: Thanks @j08691, but what did you suggest me is different. Instead of having "2 days ago" I want "Tuesday at 1:35pm" like in Facebook.